# Creating new pandas dataframe based on existing columns with duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like

```
Event     Person     Data  
Event1    Person1    Data1
Event1    Person2    Data2
Event1    Person3    Data3
Event2    Person1    Data4
Event2    Person2    Data5
Event2    Person3    Data6
```

and so on. I would like to create a new dataframe where the rows are the people (removing duplicates) and the columns are the events, and each cell is the particular datapoint corresponding to that event and that person. I can obviously just create a new dataframe and populate it iterating through the rows and columns of that dataframe, but I'm wondering if there's a slicker way?

Answer (score 1):

Use [df.pivot()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)

```
df.pivot(columns='Event', values='data', index='Person')
```

Output:

```
Event     Event1   Event2
Person      
Person1   Data1    Data4
Person2   Data2    Data5
Person3   Data3    Data6
```

Comment: Worked like a charm -- thank you!